# Xcode ghost XIB?

Tags: xcode, xib

I'm trying to change the user interface on Vice (c64 emulator) and I'm a newbie in macOS programming. I can't modify the existing XIB because the events do nothing. Checking better I noticed that there are several XIB, can someone explain me what does this mean?

[image]

Comment: If you're new, may as well ask: are you sure you want to use `Objective-C` over `Swift`? Swift is Apple's newest programming language (from 2014) and will be more up-to-date with the latest APIs. Only asking so you don't learn too much Objective-C (if you didn't know it already) so you don't need to relearn another language. :)

Comment: I'm working on VICE ( 64 emulator ), I want to change its user interface. Anything is written in objective C, so I'm using objective C.